# Grails. GORM. Error creating new instances

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I've integrated the existing hibernate mappings into a grails application. Dynamic finders works ok, also foreign keys are resolved ok. But I can't save new instances of domain classes.

Note: I don't have an id field in my domain classes, all primary keys have custom names (e.g. carId, houseId). Because of this ClassName.get(id) does not work, to workaround this I'm using dynamic finders (e.g. findByCarId). I think this is also the issue with creating instances.
The exception I got is the following :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: xxx.xxx.DomainClassName
```

It seems to be a problem related to the entity-name parameter, the existing entity-name is DomainClassName but grails try to find the entity xxx.xxx.DomainCalssName (fully qualified name) and does not find it.

Some suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should customize the id generator and the column it maps to as follows:

```
static mapping = {
   id column:'carId', type:'integer'
}
```

Comment: Can I do this not touching existing java classes and their mappings ?

Comment: so, if u have java classes, u have to use hibernate.cfg.xml. Put it to grails-app/conf/hibernate directory. You can generate this file with 'grails create-hibernate-cfg-xml' (see grails docs). Do not forget to put *hbm.xml for domain classes in the same directory(grails-app/conf/hibernate).

Comment: I've already done this, I'm using the domain for retrieving data and updating it(the issue concern creating new instances). The statement that you wrote, where to write it ?

Comment: 'grails create-hibernate-cfg-xml' - it's command. see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/create-hibernate-cfg-xml.html and http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html

Comment: this command generates an empty cfg.xml file, without any mappings

Comment: you forgot define *.hbm.xml files for all your domain java classes.

Comment: all hbm.xml are defined, they are mapping files used for a long time in production, also the class files and the cfg.xml file, I already have them all, and the integration past successful except one thing, I can't create new instances, when trying to create one I get the error I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a issue with the naming of you hbm.xml mappings, this has nothing to do with grails particularly. You should check for your entity-name attribute from those mappings. [See this post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1013357) for more details.

Comment: the issue is that when updating or requesting domain instances, everything is ok, grails operate with the entity name specified in hbm.xml file, but when doing insertion, I don't know because of what, but he doesn't see the entity-name from mapping, and take the fully qualified name of the class (which is hibernate default if entity-name param is missing), which of course is not mapped.